# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1: show a progress bar while uploading an image/video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ipad, ios5

I want to show a progress bar while my iOS app is uploading a video to Facebook. 
I tried the methods shown in this question:

[Facebook iPhone SDK: show a progress bar while uploading an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713841/facebook-iphone-sdk-show-a-progress-bar-while-uploading-an-image)

But it's not working in the new Facebook SDK 3.1. Any ideas how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to hack the Facebook source. I simply add MBProgressBar to the center of my view and darken it so that the users know they have to wait. In the Facebook completion delegate, I removed all the visual effects. This is all very simple and work.

Comment: The problem with this is that they don't know how long they have to wait. So if the video is very big, there is no way for them knowing if it's uploading or the application just hung...

Comment: You need to know the speed of your network to display a proper progress. It'll be very hard to dig inside the Facebook source for it. But trust me, you don't need to do it. In a large application even Dropbox and Skydrive, they simply estimate an upper bound for the upload. That's why you see sometimes you goto 99% and it stays there for a while and sometimes the upload finishes like 60%. You should not worry too much, just divide the size of the video by a reasonable average speed upload speed.

Comment: My users never complained. They see that they need to wait. If it's a very big video, you might show an alert box warning them or just do the upload in the background.